# how to handle mongoose connection reset

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, crash, connection

I am attempting to handle a connection reset using a mongoose connection to a mongo database.  With the code below, if the database connection gets reset or disconnected, the app will just crash with a message below.  I do hit the `connection.on('disconnected...`, but not the catch statement.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.on('open', function ()
{
    console.log('connected.');
});
connection.on('error', error =>
{
    console.log('Error: connection failed!\r\n' + error );
});
connection.on('disconnected', error =>
{
    console.log('Error: disconnected!\r\n' + error);
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true  } )
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error catch:\r\n' + error);
    }) ;
```

The error message is:

```
Error: NorthStar Mongo database disconnected!
undefined
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\work_local\NorthStar\NorthStar V2\api\NorthStar-V2-api\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:340:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Thanks for any help,
Mike

Comment: The catch block is for the initial connection error. Any other connection error should be handled via the events handler. Have you attempted re-connecting in the `connection.on('disconnected')` event handler?

Comment: To clarify, the app is crashing when the mongo server is shutdown.  I am not asking about reconnecting.  I just want to prevent the app from crashing.